# Defining bounded context boundaries

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm having trouble defining the boundaries of my bounded context(s). I have the following, simplified/incomplete, versions of the classes in my domain. All of these classes are unique so they are Entities and I think they should be AR's as well, though I'm less sure about that last point. A Customer, User and Carrier are necessary to make a load, but they can all obviously exist without a load. They have validation and other actions that must be completed before they can be added to a Load. User is responsible for initiating CRUD operations on Customer, Carrier and Loads which include adding Carriers and Customers to Loads.

Should Customers, Carriers, Loads and Users each be AR's and/or have their own bounded contexts?

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public CustomerStatus Status { get; protected set; }
}

public class Carrier
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public CarrierStatus Status { get; protected set; }
}

public class User
{

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public Role Role { get; protected set; }
}


public class Load
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public LoadStatus Status { get; protected set; }

    public Guid CustomerId { get; protected set; }

    public Guid CarrierId { get; protected set; }

    public Address Origin { get; protected set; }

    public Address Destination { get; protected set; }

    public string Commodity { get; protected set; }

}
```

Comment: No one can answer your question about bounded contexts without a much greater understanding of your particular domain. Each of the classes you’ve specified might be its own AR however.

Comment: That's how I define bounded context boundaries: https://medium.com/@wrong.about/ddd-strategic-patterns-how-to-define-bounded-contexts-2dc70927976e

Comment: @Zapadlo I think I will make separate BCs for each of these sub domains and make them AR's as well.

Comment: That can make sense -- I just don't have enough details about your domain. If these ARs are involved in some business process, then using saga might be a good fit. Here is a more higher-level example of it: https://medium.com/@wrong.about/service-boundaries-identification-example-in-e-commerce-a2c01a1b8ee9 , and this is more lower-level example: https://medium.com/@wrong.about/event-driven-architecture-implementation-140c51820845 . If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this question may not be a good question since the rules for defining BC's are fluid. I have decided to make each of the sub domains I mentioned their own BC's.